# Change color in default options when printing on yosemite

Tags: printing, cups

We've got the following printer setup:

```
Driver:     Brother MFC-L9550CDW-AirPrint (color, 2-sided printing)
Connection: dnssd://PRINTER._ipp._tcp.local./?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-30055c4b125b
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=one-sided
```

This information comes straight from CUPS. In there I tried to "Set Default Options" for that printer. What does work out but, I changed the "Color Mode" to "Grayscale". Unfortunately the default preset remains like it was (the Black & White checkbox doesn't get checked).

What am I doing wrong? How can I change the default printer preset or default printer settings to be Black & White?

So yea... **[this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16030/)** doesn't work.

Comment: Greyscale is not the same as black & white, btw

Comment: @Tetsujin I know but why doesn't it show Black & White than?