# Dell Color Laser 1320c with Mac OS 10.15 Catalina: Filter failed

Tags: printing, catalina

After upgrading to Mac OS 10.15 Catalina, trying to print with a Dell Color Laser 1320c leads to the error message: Filter failed (German: Filter fehlgeschlagen).

Answer (score 9):

This fixes the "Filter failed" (German: "Filter fehlgeschlagen") error with Dell Color Laser 1320c printers under Mac OS 10.15 Catalina by leveraging the Fuji Xerox C525A printer driver which is similar to the native Dell driver.

1. User steveham modified the original driver so it could install on all macOS versions greater than 10.7. Download the modified driver here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aotekhnsj7ox7e4/Fuji%20Xerox%20Print%20Plug-in%20Installer%20Modified.pkg?dl=0
2. Install the .pkg file
3. Go to System Preferences - Printers & Scanners
4. Click on the + sign to add a printer
5. Connect your Dell 1320c printer via USB and turn it on. It should soon appear in the list as a USB printer. Select it.
6. Under the Use drop down menu, choose Select Software. Change the driver to be the newly installed FX DocuPrint C525 A-AP v3.2 and click Add.
   [image]
   [image]
7. On the next screen leave Memory Capacity at 64MB.  Change the Optional Tray Module to be 250 Sheet Feeder and click OK.
   [image]
8. Finally you need to change the default printer settings to always print from the tray.  We do this from the CUPS Web Interface.  Open a web browser and go to http://localhost:631/printers/.  If you get a screen saying Web Interface is Disabled, open a Terminal window and run "cupsctl WebInterface=yes".
9. Choose Dell_Color_Laser_1320c from the list of printers. In the next window under the Administration drop down menu, choose Set Default Options.
   [image]
10. In the Basic tab change the Paper Source to be Tray 1 (250 Sheets)
    [image]
11. (Optional) Change other settings in the other tabs. For example, in the General tab you may want to turn Collated on and change the Media Size to be the paper size you will normally be printing with.
12. Click Set Default Options to save these settings for your printer. Enter your username and password when requested.

Comment: I can confirm the solution given by alsdkjasdlkja works. I only have 1 addition. I first tried to change the driver of my already installed Dell Color Laser 1320c instead of removing it and reinstalling it. This didn't work. I couldn't select a paper tray when trying to print something. When I deleted the old printer and reinstalled it with the FX driver, everything worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you @alsdkjasdlkja for your solution. I have a Dell 1320c and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: In the Options section (Step 11) - I had to choose the Fuji Xerox Features and set the tray to 250, otherwise it was always printing from the by-pass tray.

Comment: @alsdkjasdlkja Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of money. I thought my printer is broken, no it's clear, the Dell driver support for macOS is "Schrott".

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'd already bought a shitty inkjet printer, but now I can enjoy the smell of fresh ozon once more! One tip, you can change the default to use the Tray by accessing the CUPS webinterface. See here for more information: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/37568/5993.

Comment: Fuji seem to have removed the driver ("End of Service"). Does anyone have a working link to it?