# Will any AirPrint-compatible printer work with macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, printing, compatibility, airprint

There seems to be a lot of confusion around which printers can be made to work with macOS Catalina. Now that 32-bit print drivers are no longer supported on Catalina, that seems to break compatibility with a lot of older consumer-grade printers.

But what about AirPrint? Since AirPrint seems to always work from an iOS device without needing to install any driver, does that also guarantee that the printer would work with macOS Catalina?