# Dell Color Laser 1320c with macOS 10.15 Catalina: FX Docuprint Driver - Set Paper Tray option

Tags: catalina, printing

I followed the two answers from [Dell Color Laser 1320c with Mac OS 10.15 Catalina: Filter failed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373395/dell-color-laser-1320c-with-mac-os-10-15-catalina-filter-failed) including removing and re-adding the printer. These were very helpful - thank you! By using the FX Docuprint C525 A-AP v3.2 Driver software I can now print via the manual feed but not the paper tray.

In the print dialogue screen I did not see all the content from the previous post:
[image]

Maybe I'm missing something in this Layout step? Maybe I need to be in "Admin" mode or something?

In the printer settings I can choose from : [image]

No matter the choice output only prints via the manual feed.

In the print job presets from Pages, I see that the Fuji Xerox is set for the alternate paper source. Maybe if this could be changed I'd be in business?

Thanks in advance for any insights and suggestions!

Comment: This is not really a macOS issue but rather a PPD programming/config issue.  Looking on Dell's website, the [user guide](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_printers_main/esuprt_printers_color_laser/dell-1320c_user%27s%20guide_en-us.pdf) specifically says "Windows Only."  You might find assistance on http://www.openprinting.org/drivers

Comment: Thank you for this comment - I will check out the site suggested.

Comment: Just for added clarification, Dell actaully does provide a Mac driver, just that it does not support Catalina.   I have now found in the Layout options that I can choose the Fuji Xerox layout and select the 250-sheet printer tray. It's just that the setting is not sticking from one print job to the next and needs to be re-selected each time. In the Mac printer preferences the option is set to use this tray.

Comment: Can you link to the driver?  Does it support Mojave?  I can't see why it won't work in Catalina unless it's 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Allan for your input which helped move toward a solution. Yes, the issue with the Dell driver is that it is 32-bit.

Using the FX Docuprint C525 A-AP v3.2 Driver software as outlined above and in the referenced link I am now printing reliably from this printer via the paper tray.

I now see where the settings with the Fuji Xerox layout including the paper tray can be saved as a Preset. Once saved it is easily reusable.