# How to get Dell 1320c working on iMac with 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: catalina, imac, printing

I'm hoping somebody could direct me to a solution for my printer problem.  I just switched to an iMac after being a lifelong PC user and love the hardware and software on the iMac but can't get my printer going.

I have followed the links in similar questions but Xerox has ended support for the *Docuprint C525a* printer.  Their support site sends you to a page to discuss a new printer, which people say has similar drivers to the Dell 1320c so I wondered if somebody could help with a working link for those drivers.

Comment: Welcome to AD! Please add links to the similar questions you mention, also what does happen if you try to install the Dell 1320c drivers from https://www.dell.com/support/home/de-ch/product-support/product/dell-1320c/drivers ?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the welcome https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373395/dell-color-laser-1320c-with-mac-os-10-15-catalina-filter-failed. Have also tried the link you added but get a message saying it can't be opened because the developer can't be verified, I have allowed the apps downloaded from App store and identified developers but it still comes up.

Comment: Hmmm… "Note: Dell is aware that there are no Laser printer drivers for macOS 10.15, also known as macOS Catalina. Due to circumstances beyond our control, Dell will not be able to offer Laser printer drivers for macOS Catalina." from https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000129214/installing-dell-laser-printers-on-apple-mac-systems 'Word on the street' is this is due to Dell selling the entire printer division off several years ago.

Comment: Right-click on the application and select Open the first time to launch it, this will help to get around the message.

Comment: I have tried again but it still comes up with the same message saying developer isn't authorised or something along those lines the asks if I want remove to bin or cancel.now I have windows 10 working with bootcamp I can at least use the printer that way so it's not too much of a problem now as I don't need the print facilities too often.

Comment: You can often get an unsupported printer to work by choosing the generic Postscript printer driver that comes with macOS. You usually won't get any of the printer's special features but you should be able to print.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found a workaround to get the printer working without a second pc to turn it into a network printer... Installed Windows 10 on the iMac using Bootcamp, took a couple of hours but can at least use the printer.

Comment: Instead of Bootcamp, I would run a VirtualBox VM with limited resources so you don't have to shutdown your Mac to print a document.  You just spin up the VM when needed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unfortunately, this printer is very unlikely to be compatible with Catalina.

Looking at the [OpenPrinting website for supported Xerox printers](https://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/Xerox), the Docuprint C525a printer isn't listed.  In fact, the entire C5 line is nowhere to be found. There's even less listed for [Dell](https://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/Dell) and the only printer in the 13** series is tagged as "mostly working."

It's important to note that [OpenPrinting](https://openprinting.github.io/about-us/) provides the CUPS filters and PPDs that are used on Unix/Linux operating systems.  [CUPS is the Common Unix Printing](http://www.cups.org/) System (standards based, open source) developed by Apple.

It's not likely a standalone network print server will solve your issue here as the print server doesn't magically have every driver for every printer.  In fact, it just acts as a "pass through" - your computer will still need the printer drivers to print to it.

If you must use this printer, instead of using Bootcamp, use a VM through [VirtualBox](https://virtualbox.org) (free).  This allows you to spin up the Windows machine with the correct drivers *without* having to shutdown macOS and boot Windows.  Once you're done, you just close the VM and continue on.